# ListView element's sub element is repeating after a certain position

Tags: android, listview, convertview

I have a listView which is working/displaying some data as Title and subtitle ,all is working fine but whenever I scroll up the list or the convertView recycles, the subtitle of last element get repeated while the Title is not, whats the issue..

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    m_oActivatedProfilePreferences =m_oContext.getSharedPreferences(m_kSHARED_PREF_PROFILE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final CProfileDataSource profileDataSource = new CProfileDataSource(m_oContext);
    final List<CUserProfile> profileName = profileDataSource.getAllProfiles();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_description,parent,false);
        viewHolder.m_profileName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilename);
        viewHolder.m_radioButton=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        viewHolder.m_profileDetails=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pro_details);
        viewHolder.m_profileLyt=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile);
        if(position==0)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.general_profile_description);
        }else if(position==1)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.sleep_profile_description);
        }else if(position==2)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.ssaver_profile_description);
        }else
        {
           //here for the 8th position of list it displays the text as position 0

            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.profile_desc);
        }
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.m_radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.m_radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
  return convertView;
}
```

under the "else" part the "viewHolder.m_profileDetails" set their text as position number 0, while it's position is 8 or 9 in the list.

```
private static class ViewHolder{
    RadioButton m_radioButton;
    TextView m_profileName;
    TextView m_profileDetails;
    LinearLayout m_profileLyt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this getView method:-

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    m_oActivatedProfilePreferences =m_oContext.getSharedPreferences(m_kSHARED_PREF_PROFILE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final CProfileDataSource profileDataSource = new CProfileDataSource(m_oContext);
    final List<CUserProfile> profileName = profileDataSource.getAllProfiles();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        //always define viewholder object here and also link your xml components like textview using findViewById() method.

        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_description,parent,false);
        viewHolder.m_profileName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilename);
        viewHolder.m_radioButton=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        viewHolder.m_profileDetails=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pro_details);
        viewHolder.m_profileLyt=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.m_radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        // This tag viewHolder object helps you to reuse your object.
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.m_radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    // Always do setText(),onClick like operation on components here so here viewHolder decide which UI components need to use.

    if(position==0)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.general_profile_description);
        }else if(position==1)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.sleep_profile_description);
        }else if(position==2)
        {
            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.ssaver_profile_description);
        }else
        {
           //here for the 8th position of list it displays the text as position 0

            viewHolder.m_profileDetails.setText(R.string.profile_desc);
        }
  return convertView;
}
```

Let me know if getting any error in it

Comment: great,your code is right but you have doing wrong arrangement of code thats why your view reuse only first four items created

Comment: Check getView() method now I have put comments which helps you to understand actual working of list adapters and use of viewHolder class.